# Is there a way to close all connections in the pool for the SqlClient provider

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I would like to close all idle connections in the SqlClient connection pool.  Is there a documented method for doing this?

The issue is that as part of the normal processing of this application (A testing harness) I need to drop the database and recreate it at the start of each test scenerio.  Obviously I can't drop the database with active connections (active from Sql Server's point of view not the client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.  Specific database providers may provide a way of doing this.  SqlClient provides a similar feature via SqlConnection.ClearPool and SqlConnection.ClearAllPools -- but these do not close any open connections, they just clear out connections that have been returned to the pool.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted --- it's the idle connections still open in the pool that was causing the bother.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason do to this.  If you have a need to do this, it probably indicates that you have a leak somewhere else in the application and should try to find out where you aren't disposing of your connections properly.

FWIW, I don't believe there is a way to do this for all providers consistently, but based on what I mentioned above, there should be no **need** to do this.

Comment: You're right in nearly all situations, the connection pool can be left alone, however my issue is an edge case in that I need to be able as part of a long running test, I need to be able to drop the database and recreate it.  Can't do that with active connections.

Comment: @Ralph interesting point about droping a DB, you should add this to your question.